# How to avoid being behind NAT in Azure Ubuntu VM

Tags: azure, nat, azure-networking

I am looking to create an Ubuntu VM in Azure whose IP address *is* the pubic facing one.
The VM should *NOT* be behind a NAT/Firewall.

Is this possible in Azure?
If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

The instructions on how to do this are listed in the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal). These are the cli commands you can use to achieve this:

```
az group create --name myResourceGroup --location eastus

az vm create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myVM \
  --image UbuntuLTS \
  --admin-username azureuser \
  --generate-ssh-keys \
  --public-ip-address myPublicIpAddress \
  --public-ip-address-allocation static

az network public-ip show \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myPublicIpAddress \
  --query [ipAddress,publicIpAllocationMethod,sku] \
  --output table
```

The documentation contains instructions for the portal and powershell as well.